# Set comparison optimization

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing, vectorization

#### Description

I have two large lists of sets

```py
A = [ {...}, ..., {...} ]
B = [ {...}, ..., {...} ]
```

I'm performing a very cost-intensive list comprehension that for every element in every set in A checks if there is a match with any element in B's sets and if so returns B's respective sets.

```py
[find_sets(i) for i in A]
```

#### Example

A minimal example looks like this:

```
import secrets

# create sample data 
def generate_random_strings(num_strings, string_length):
    random_strings = []
    for i in range(num_strings):
        random_strings.append(secrets.token_hex(string_length))
    random_strings = set(random_strings)
    return random_strings

A = [generate_random_strings(5, 1) for i in range(10000)]
B = [generate_random_strings(5, 1) for i in range(10000)]

# set checker 
def find_sets(A):
    matching_sets = []
    for b_set in B:
        if A & b_set:
            matching_sets.append(b_set)
    return matching_sets

result = [find_set(i) for i in A]
```

#### Multiprocessing

It's obviously faster on all my 32 CPU cores:

```py
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=32)
results = process_map(find_sets, A, chunksize=100)
```

#### Problem

While for a few thousand elements for A and B the list comprehension runs fairly fast on my machine and multiprocessing helps to scale it up to like 50.000 elements, it becomes very slow for 500.000 elements in each list which is my actual size.

Is there any way to speed up my function code-wise with vectorization, hashing the sets before or working with some kind of optimized data types (frozensets didn't help)?

Comment: Sets already hashed, so "hashing the sets" won't do anything

Comment: You could change it to use a list comprehension, use a JIT compiler like Numba, you could increase the chunk size so that your processes don't have to go back to get more data as often, write more optimized code with Cython, etc.. I'm not sure if there's much else you can do

Comment: @AhmedAEK yes, like in the example, the sets contain strings. Here, I shortened them but in my case they have like 10-100 characters.

Comment: What percentage of the sets in A have no matches in B?

Comment: @JonSG little, like max. 5%. Ideally all have precisely one match.

Comment: Side note: you have a bug in `generate_random_strings` if the same string is generated then the output won't be of length `num_strings`. You can use a `while` loop to check until the length == `num_strings`

Comment: Since you expect "few" matches and ideally 1, for any given list in "A" most of the lists in "B" will be misses.  Create a new list C that is a chunked version of "B" such that the elements of C are sets of the say chunks of 10 rows from B concatenated together.  Now C can be searched and hopefully each failed search on an item in C is as efficient as having searched 10 rows of "B".  If there is a match search the corresponding chunk of rows for B to find the actual match

Comment: Very interesting approach! Sounds like smart indexing. I'm wondering whether there is already some kind of library that does this automatically and somehow finds a near-optimal joined set size.

Comment: each set in B have the same size?

Comment: @Corralien no, they don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This runs an order of magnitude faster in my tests:

```py
import collections

reverse_map = collections.defaultdict(set)
for idx, elements in enumerate(B):
    for element in elements:
        reverse_map[element].add(idx)

def find_sets(A):
    union = set()
    emptyset = set()
    for element in A:
        union |= reverse_map.get(element, emptyset)
    return [B[idx] for idx in union]
```

Comment: This is brilliant! It's around 15 times faster than my initial solution! Didn't know about defaultdict

Comment: Update: With multiprocessing on 32 cores for each ~600.000 elements in A and B it reduced my computation time from ~3h to only 12s which is a speedup of x900!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a comprehension instead of `find_sets`:

```
 result = [[b for b in B if a & b] for i in A]
```

Comment: I like the simplicity but unfortunately speed-wise it's on par (or slightly slower) than my initial solution.

Comment: This is absolutely true, I was trying to work out a better solution.